# How to call MainActivity method in a java class?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying ways to call my MainActivity method into my doWork in java class in android studio. But I'm not getting it. Is there any way to call this method ?

Class in the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    protected double latitude, longitude;
    TextView txtLat, txtLng;

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void LocalizarUsuario(){

        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLat);
        txtLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLng);


        locationManager =(LocationManager)

                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity .this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
    }
}
```

Java class with the doWork

```
public class WorkerClass extends Worker {
    public WorkerClass(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

             LocalizarUsuario();


        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You cannot call such a function. It makes no sense to make public functions in an activity class as you have no pointer to an activity.

Comment: @blackapps Is there anything I can do? If I make a class just for this method, can I start this method in java class?

Comment: Well try and post your code to make clear what you have in mind. I have no idea why you need so much classes.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you could place the WorkerClass into the MainActivity (inner class) or if you want to use the WorkerClass only from the MainActivity, you could pass the instance of

Comment: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }    class Inner {
 public class WorkerClass extends Worker {

              public WorkerClass(
                        @NonNull Context context,
                        @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
                    super(context, params);
                }

                @Override
                public Result doWork() {

                    return Result.success();
                }
        }
    }
}`       so?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).